# error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: ios, node.js, encryption

I am using the following function to [verify an iOS assertion object on my server](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server):

```
const cbor = require("cbor");
const crypto = require("crypto");

function verifyAssertion(assertionString, clientDataString, attestKeyID) {
    // Convert Base64 string to Buffer
    let assertionBuffer = Buffer.from(assertionString, 'base64');
    let clientDataBuffer = Buffer.from(clientDataString, 'base64');
    try {
        let assert = cbor.decodeAllSync(assertionBuffer)[0];
        console.log(`verifyAssertion() assert: ${assert}`);
        let authData = assert.authenticatorData; // buffer
        let signature = assert.signature; // buffer
        console.log(`verifyAssertion() authData: ${authData}`);
        console.log(`verifyAssertion() signature: ${signature}`);
        // compute client Data Hash
        let clientDataHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(clientDataBuffer).digest('base64');
        let clientDataHashBuffer = Buffer.from(clientDataHash, 'base64');
        console.log("clientDataHashBuffer: ", clientDataHashBuffer);
        // compute composite hash
        let compositeBuffer = Buffer.concat([authData, clientDataHashBuffer]);
        let nonce = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(compositeBuffer).digest('base64'); // base64 string
        let nonceBuffer = Buffer.from(nonce, 'base64');
        console.log("nonce: ", nonce);
        // load public key
        console.log("attestKeyID: ", attestKeyID);
        let keyObj = crypto.createPublicKey(attestKeyID);
        console.log("keyObj: ", keyObj);
        // verify signature
        let verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha256').update(nonceBuffer);
        let sign_verify = verifier.verify(keyObj, signature);
        console.log("sign_verify: ", sign_verify);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`verifyAssertion() error: ${e}`);
    }
}
```

However, `crypto.createPublicKey(attestKeyID)` is causing the following error:

`verifyAssertion() error: Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`

Here is the iOS code that sends the:

1. Assertion object (as a base64 string)
2. Client data (as a base64 string)
3. keyId generated from [generateKey()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573913-generatekey?language=swift)

to my server:

```
    guard let clientData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(adjustedData) else { return }
    let clientDataHash = Data(SHA256.hash(data: clientData))
    service.generateAssertion(attestKeyID, clientDataHash: clientDataHash) { assertion, err in
        guard error == nil else { return print("generateAssertion() error: \(error)") }
        let assertionString = assertion?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
        let clientDataString = clientData.base64EncodedString()
        adjustedData["attestKeyID"] = attestKeyID
        adjustedData["assertionString"] = assertionString
        adjustedData["clientData"] = clientDataString
        functions.httpsCallable(name).call(adjustedData){ (result, error) in
            completion(result, error)
            print("function \(name) completed")
        }
    }
```

Any idea why I am getting that error?

Comment: `crypto.createPublicKey(attestKeyID)` expects a PEM encoded key, i.e. a key with header (e.g. _-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----_) and footer (e.g. _-----END PUBLIC KEY-----_). The error message says that the header is missing.

Comment: Any idea how to convert a public key to a PEM encoded key? @Topaco

Comment: It depends on the format and encoding of your public key, which you don't say anything about. Post the missing information or a test key (since it's a public key, you can also post it).

Comment: I did say that my public key was generated from generateKey(): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573913-generatekey?language=swift - the public key is `SBeTG+fSV3WR2nHLqj2Yuy0OT/oJ/ByoY+JdYTkC8zM=` @Topaco does that help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS, but according to the linked description `generateKey()` generates a key pair in a _Secure Enclave_ (which is presumably some kind of key store) and returns only an identifier. If `attestKeyID` is this identifier, then NodeJS can't do anything with it, because it's not a key. You need to find a way to export the (public) key from the _Secure Enclave_. Usually you can specify format and encoding for an export. Here you have to use a format (e.g. X.509/SPKI or PKCS#1) and encoding (e.g. PEM or DER) that NodeJS supports.